# Fine grained locking in C

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, locking, mutual-exclusion

I have this code for swapping elements:

```
   atomic{
       int temp = a[i];
       a[i] =a[j];
       a[j] = temp;
  }
```

How would I implement this using fine-grained locking to achieve the same effect?

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: What library are you using for paralelizing ?

Comment: I think it is just a generalised version of an atomic operation. I saw it in an exam paper and they asked for the fine-grained locking version of it.

Comment: I'm not coding it, more like writing it on paper for illustration purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mutex to achieve this effect,

```
mutex.lock();
atomic
{
   int temp = a[i];
   a[i] =a[j];
   a[j] = temp;
}
mutex.unlock();
```

If there are multiple threads you can use POSIX style Read/Write locks as follows,

```
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(rw_lock_ptr);
atomic
{
   int temp = a[i];
   a[i] =a[j];
   a[j] = temp;
}
pthread_rwlock_unlock(rw_lock_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you mean some classical explicit locking approach, such as mutexes.

That would require not only the swapping code, but also all the places where `a[]` is accessed, to be protected by the mutex. Otherwise you can't be sure that some other thread isn't in the process of reading from `a[]`, as you do the swap.

Not sure 100% about the semantics of your `atomic`{}` block, and how that would work to protect against the same problem (just becase the swap itself happens atomically, it could still "mix" badly with code executing in a different thread and lead to problems).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a[i] and a[j] can be accessed by other threads, acquire a mutex whenever your code access those elements.